# Getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error I update property of a Component from another Component

Tags: angular6

The demo is available here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a9wcee

Please open the console window to see the error.

Description
I have a `Bootstrap` component `ComponentA` which should start up in two different ways depending on the application's startup process. Say if the application is started using url `home.com` then `ComponentA` should not show a pop up dialog on startup but if the application is started using `home.com;signup` then the application should show a pop up.

I have read that `Input` doesn't work for bootstrap components so I am passing an attribute to `ComponentA` from my `index.html` as a "startup context".

```
<comp-a someAttr="someValue"></comp-a> <!--depending on whether someAttr is empty ("") or not, the pop should not be shown or shown respectively -->
```

and `ComponentA`'s uses a `DialogComponent` in its template as follows

```
<comp-dialog [message]=""></comp-dialog> <!-- I want the input to ComponentB to be empty to begin with -->
```

`ComponentB` is a `Bootstrap` `css` dialog box and takes an `Input` message which it shows when the dialog becomes visible. The tricky bit is that `ComponentB` is in `ComponentA`'s template and thus Angular initialised it as part of `ComponentA`'s start up but before `ComponentA`'s start up finished, `ComponentA` tries to change `ComponentB` (the `message` property) if it determines that it has to show the dialog box (`ComponentB`) (by checking the attribute).  I think this is creating issues with `Change Detection` and I am `Angular` is throwing `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error. How could I redesign the component interaction

The code snippets of `ComponentA` are

- Check how I was started.

  ```
   ngAfterViewChecked(){
      this.signup = this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('signup'); //get the attribute
      this.isSignupProcess();//check if ComponentB needs to be shown and update its message property
    }

    isSignupProcess(){
      console.log("sign up is "+this.signup)
      if(this.signup!==""){ //show ComponentB
        if(this.signup === "success") {
          this.showDialog("Signup was successful",new DialogContext("","")) //set message property of ComponentB
        }else if(this.signup === "error") {
          this.showDialog("Error: Signup wasn't successful",new DialogContext("",""))
        } else {
          this.showDialog("Unrecognised message: "+this.signup,new DialogContext("",""))
        }
        this.signup = ""; //no need to show ComponentB

      } else {

      }
  ```

  }

the logic to update `message` property of `ComponentB` and show it is

```
showDialog(message:string,context:DialogContext) {

    this.dialogComponent.dialogShow(message,context);
  }
```

`ComponentB` simply calls `Bootstrap`'s modal function

```
dialogShow(message:string, context:DialogContext){
    this.dialogContext = context;
    this.dialogMessage = message;
    console.log("dialog got context ",this.dialogContext);
    $(this.dialogRef.nativeElement).modal('show');

  }
```

the `html` of `ComponentB` is

```
<div #modal class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id={{dialogID}}>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">CodingJedi</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="dialogHide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{dialogMessage}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="dialogHide()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article explains well what causes the error - https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Quoting from the link, Change detection in Angular goes through the following steps
    1) update bound properties for all child components/directives i.e.  and interpolation values {{}}
    2) call ngOnInit, OnChanges and ngDoCheck lifecycle hooks on all child components/directives
    3) update DOM for the current component
    4) run change detection for a child component
    5) call ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook for all child components/directives

After each operation Angular remembers what values it used to perform an operation.
They are stored in the oldValues property of the component view.

After the checks have been done for all components, Angular compares the current values with the ones it remembers from the previous digest cycle:
      1) check that values passed down to the child components are the same as the values that would be used to update properties of these components now
      2) check that values used to update the DOM elements are the same as the values that would be used to update these elements now
      3) perform the same checks for all child components

After this, Angular runs a verification cycle to check that the values used to create Child Components and in DOM are still the same otherwise the change detection will not stabalise after one cycle and could end in infinite loop. If Angular finds that the value used to create a child component or used on DOM has changed before the current change detection cycle has finished then it will throw `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

In my code, DialogComponent is created with initial values of `dialogMessage` and `dialogContext`. Now, depending on how the app got started, I want to update the message and show the dialog box. If I just update the `dialogMessage`, Angular will give error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` because the value of `dialogMessage` had changed before the current change detection cycle finished.

There are two ways to fix the issue. Use `setTimeout` to create the next task which will be executed once  the current change detection task finishes OR  after changing the `dialogMessage` of `DialogBoxComponent`, run change detection again using `detectChanges()`

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    setTimeout(()=>this.isSignupProcess());

    }

    OR
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    this.isSignupProcess(); 
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
```